# Default constructor behavior when multiple constructors defined

Tags: c++, class-constructors

Are default constructors called automatically when another constructor is defined with parameters or do I have to scope to it with : objectName() like the following:

```
Class TextFileParse {
public:
    TextFileParse() = default;
    TextFileParse( wstring fileName ) : TextFileParse()
    {
        Load( fileName );
    }
};
```

What if I define the constructor instead of the default and it initializes and calls other methods, do I have to scope to it then?  I am working with codes bases that do both and not sure how each are acting (static .lib, I only have headers to trace into).  Thank you

Comment: I can't see that there would be much point to using delegation in this case, since the default constructor does nothing.

Comment: Constructors do not call each other unless you delegate. Base class constructors and data member constructors can be implicitly called though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > Are default constructors called automatically when another constructor is defined with parameters?

No, they aren't.

> > What if I define the constructor instead of the default and it initializes and calls other methods, do I have to scope to it then?

Yes, if you want to use a functionality from the another constructor you need to use delegating constructors.

As a general rule, *no constructors automatically call other constructors*. You need either use delegating constructors (since *C++11*) or move the common logic into separate methods which are called from multiple constructors.